# Link suddenly not click-able after media-query

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm officially stumped. After including a simple jQuery slideUp script in the bottom of my page (to show/hide certain divs onclick), two links in my navbar (which is just 2 ul's) are no longer "clickable"-- this ONLY happens when the browser size is shrunk to a certain width (still at a reasonable size). They are clickable and the jQuery works fine with the browser window is wider. ANY HELP would be tremendously appreciated. I am ready to throw my computer out the window.

Here are the links:

```
    <ul id="second">
    <li><a id="partials/art.html">art</a></li>
    <li><a href="#designinfo" class="navlink">   design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#illustrationinfo" class="navlink">illustration</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="first">
    <li><a href="#aboutinfo" class="navlink">   about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contactinfo" class="navlink">   contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is an example of one of the div's that is supposed to open. In fact, this is one that is not opening (The "about" link is one that isn't clickable, for some reason).

```
            <div id="aboutinfo" class="info">
            <div id="bio">

     <p> bio info goes here </p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

The only CSS that really comes into play here is:

```
         .info{
          display:none;
           }
```

And here is the jquery:

```
    <script>

   $('.navlink').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));
  if(!targetDiv.is(':visible')){
$('.info').slideUp();
targetDiv.slideDown();
 }
   else{$('.info').slideUp();
  }

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Before you throw your computer out the window, change the `var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));` to `var targetDiv = $(this).attr('href');`

Comment: That actually disabled the jquery script--  after I changed that, nothing will toggle open..

Comment: Interesting-- I just took out all my media queries, and those links that were not clickable suddenly are clickable..